# How can I filter those "Permission denied" from find output?

Tags: linux, grep, find, sed, stderr

I started using `sed` recently. One handy way I use it is to ignore unimportant lines of a log file:

```
tail -f example.com-access.log | sed '/127.0.0.1/d;/ELB-/d;/408 0 "-" "-"/d;'
```

But when I try to use it similarly with `find`, the results aren't as expected. I am trying to ignore any line that contains "Permission denied" like this:

```
find . -name "openssl" | sed '/Permission denied/d;'
```

However, I still get a whole bunch of "Permission denied" messages in `stdout`.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the correct answer below, the "Permission denied" messages are appearing in `stderr` and NOT `stdout`.

Comment: You should look into `grep`/`egrep`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't see how `grep` would help me out here.

Comment: By filtering things out of the log file that you don't want to see, of course.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not filtering anything out of a log file (except in the example), I'm trying to ignore lines returned by `find`. I can't write a regex that matches results that are unknown.

Comment: @Ben You can, however, exclude the results that you do know. (`-v`)

Comment: I have no idea what either of you are talking about.

Comment: @Ben Bluntly: `grep -v 'Permission denied'`, `grep -Ev '(Permission denied|kitchen sink)'`, etc.

Comment: @AndrewB I'm guessing you mean pipe the results of the `find` command through that `grep` command, as in: `find . -name "openssl" | grep -v "Permission denied"`. That doesn't work.

Comment: @AndrewB Yes. Thank you very much. I appreciate it. I would just like to know how, specifically, you would use `grep` to do the same thing, as I believe that is what you are telling me is possible.

Comment: Last comment, because this is about to get locked. If this works, upvote with no reply. `find . -name "openssl" 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"`

Comment: For understanding how this two output stream could work, take a look at this SO answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16283739/1765658

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is error ouput printed to **stderr**, so the `sed` command can't catch the input. The simple solution is: redirecting stderr to stdout.

```
find . -name "openssl" 2>&1 | sed '/Permission denied/d;'
```

Comment: Beat me to it. The subshell isn't necessary though.

Comment: So the error is printed to **stderr** whereas sed is reading from **stdout**? Also, could you explain "2>&1" specifically?

Comment: @Ben Output redirection only effects `STDOUT`. `2>&1` redirects file descriptor 2 (`STDERR`) to file descriptor 1 (`STDOUT`).

Comment: @Andrew: edited answer. And I think `2>1` is the same as `2>&1`.

Comment: @Gnouc Fails within mine. You should always include a `&` character to be safe.

Comment: @Gnouc: "2>1" redirects stdout (file descriptor 2) to a file named "1". It isn't the same as "2>&1", where the "&1" indicates "file descriptor 1, aka stdout".

Comment: Yeah, it's my mistake.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure why you are trying to use `sed` to remove *permission denied* messages from output of `find` - unless you are trying to learn how to use `sed`.

I would simply run this instead:

> find . -name "openssl" 2>/dev/null

Here, I'm redirecting **stderr** (file descriptor **2**) over to `/dev/null` (refer to `man null`). In other words, `2>/dev/null` simply discards everything written to **stderr**.

Comment: Great stuff. You wouldn't believe how many verbose and needlessly complex answers I've seen for this...